# Sharing Redux actions between multiple reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is a highly simplified description of the problem I'm running into with my React/Redux application:

---

**Problem description:**

Suppose I have a web app with two views, a `ProductList` view and a `ProductOfTheDay` view.  Each view has its own "store" file; holding state, reducer, actions, etc associated with the view.

Let the state structure of each store be as follows:

```
// ProductList store state  
const productListState = {
  products: Product[]
};

// ProductOfTheDay store state
const productOfTheDayState = {
  product: Product
};

// Product
interface Product {
  hasAddedToCart: boolean
  ...
}
```

When a user is on the `ProductList` view, they see a list of product UI elements (there's some `Product.tsx` component that takes in a `Product` and renders itself).  When a user is on the `ProductOfTheDay` view, they see a single product UI element.

Now, there suppose there is a button on each product UI element that allows a user to add that specific product to their shopping chart.  When this button is clicked, an `addToCart` action is dispatched, which will update the corresponding `Product` object in my state to have `hasAddedToCart: true`).

---

**Here's the issue:**

My reducers do not know *which* view the user is on when they click "Add to cart".  Consequently, they do not know whether the user is adding a product from the `ProductList` view to their cart, or is adding the product from the `ProductOfTheDay` view to their cart.  As a result, the reducers do not know whether or not they should handle the action.

---

**Solution #1:**

I can dispatch an `addToCart` action with an `index` parameter: `dispatch(addToCart(index));`.  If the `index >= 0`, then I know to have my `ProductList` reducer handle it, and my `ProductOfTheDay` reducer ignore it.   If `index === -1`, then I know to do the opposite.

I don't like this solution because it seems like a hacky way for the reducers to deduce whether or not they should handle the action.

---

**Solution #2:**

Instead of having an `addToCart` action, have `addProductFromListToCart` and `addProductOfTheDayToCart` actions.  I don't like this approach because these actions are, at the end of the day, performing essentially identical transformations on different slices of state.

---

**Solution #3:**

Add a Cart store with the following structure:

```
{
  cart: {
    [productId]: boolean
  }
}
```

Then, I can dispatch `addToCart(productId)`, and have it be handled by only the Cart reducer.  I like this approach the best so far...

---

**Request for help:**

Have others encountered this design problem?  How do you structure your actions/reducers to combat this?  If anything is unclear, let me know, and I can help clarify.

Thanks!!

Comment: why would the reducers need to know which view the action came from? the result should be the same right? add the product to the cart? do you have a cart reducer?

Comment: Given my current state structure, they need to know how to find the corresponding `Product` in my state.  The `index` parameter I am passing to `addToCart` allows each reducer to find the corresponding `Product`.  No, I do not have a Cart reducer... let me think about how that would work.

Comment: what happens after you add something to the cart? wouldn't you need to store the current cart state somewhere?

Comment: Suppose in my case that we don't have any cart state.  Maybe instead of `addToCart`, you can think of the button click as a `markProductAsFavorite` or something?

Comment: I like the idea of having a Cart store though, let me post it as a third solution.

Comment: well.. even "mark product as favorite" to ME means having a favorites array or set which is a list of product IDs. modifying the actual product seems like a bad solution to me.. and in your particular case its extra bad since you don't appear to have a "products" reducer, but reducers based on views, which is also a pretty unusual thing to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178564/discussion-between-sir-thursday-and-azium).